# math operation between 2 uint32_t returning an uint64_t

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

I'm trying to implement an operation, a function, with an interface like this one `uint64_t foo(uint32_t,uint32_t)` , so this is a simple implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint> 

uint64_t foo(const uint32_t &a, const uint32_t &b) {    
  return ((reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t &>(a)) +
          (reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t &>(b)));
}

int main() {
  uint32_t k1 = ~0;
  uint32_t k2 = 1;
  std::cout << foo(k1, k2) << "\n";
  return (0);
}
```

Now my focus is on the `reinterpret_cast` and the `+` operator.

the `+` operator should be fine where it is because it's being called by 2 `uint64_t`; so the problem is the `reinterpret_cast` ? I don't get why ...
My speculation is about the chunk of memory that is near `a` or `b`, so the result of the `reinterpret_cast` is a 50% of the original `a` or `b` and the other 50% is a random chunk of memory. I this how this cast really works ?

I already tried several versions of a `reinterpret_cast`, even with pointers, with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` essentially tells the compiler to ignore all its type-safety and just accept what you are doing.

You are saying that your reference is not a reference to a 32-bit number but to a 64-bit number. That does of course mean (in 8-bits-per-byte system), 4 bytes that could potentially contain any data are read as part of your integer. You also have a "portability" issue related to big-endian systems in particular where the more significant bytes appear first and therefore will yield a different number even if the other bytes do happen to be zero.

Your correct way to perform this is `static_cast` and not use references but "pass-by-value".

As it is, you can manage to write foo without any casting at all.

```
uint64_t foo( uint64_t a, uint64_t b ) { return a + b; }
```

and you can call it with 32-bit numbers and not worry if they overflow. (Try it with multiplying them).

Comment: the most interesting part of the `reinterpret_cast` for me is the fact that is an unconditional cast basically, so little to no overhead is possible, the is no way to reserve and clear the next chunk of memory when doing the cast ?

Comment: No, because that chunk of memory is probably already allocated to something else.  Even if it was possible it would introduce a far higher overhead than simply creating another variable on the stack.

Comment: @user2485710: Implicit conversions and `static_cast` also have no run-time overhead, just a compile-time check. `reinterpret_cast` gets rid of the compile-time check, allowing all kinds of weird and wonderful conversions whether or not they make sense. You could probably come up with some horrific bodge to reserve space and make the reference cast "work", but it's likely to be less efficient than a simple, safe value conversion.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I was actually thinking about an `union` with the 32 bit type and a 64 bit type as a filler. But I think that I'll just use `static_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying too hard. Pass by value and use `static_cast`. Also, use `uint_least32_t` or `uint_fast32_t`, whichever is more appropriate, rather than insisting on an exact size that may not exist.

Comment: what is the overhead for `static_cast` ?

Comment: @user2485710: A compile-time check. No run-time overhead (apart from the conversion itself, which you need in any case).

Comment: @MikeSeymour if the check happens at compile-time, what really happens when I pass my value at runtime ?

Comment: @user2485710: That depends on the platform and calling convention. On a 64-bit platform, there's probably no cost - simply putting the 32-bit value into a 64-bit register will probably do the right thing. On a 32-bit (or smaller) platform, it will probably write the value onto the stack (or into a register), and write a zero value next to it (or into a second register). Whatever it does, it will be the fastest way to perform the conversion, unless the compiler is hopelessly broken.

Comment: @user2485710 - the overhead is that, unlike `reinterpret_cast`, it does what you want.